# How to make Internet Explorer not open extensions

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, notepad++, file-extension

So, I had been using Notepad++ to open many be files - say, .txt, or .log, for example. And that is how I like it. One day, though, internet explorer suddenly started opening them, which I most certainly don't want. I think it might have started after an update.

Note, Windows 7, and IE 10.

So, in default programs, IE isn't set for anything like those - the only things that are set I cannot seem to remove. Anyway, .txt and friends - including .html - are not checked.

So, I don't know how to get it off. It USED to work. I tried reverting to IE 9, but the problem remains.

Note, in the description, it says Notepad++ Document, but the logo is of IE, and it opens in IE.

Any ideas?

Some pictures I cannot seem to post:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: http://snag.gy/eDBRE.jpg
http://snag.gy/fxY9k.jpg

Answer (score 2):

Have you already tried [this](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fixtheproblem/ht/default-program-windows-7.htm).  You need to associate the extension to a specific program to have a program open it by default.

Here is an article on managing your [open with](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/take-control-of-your-windows-7-open-with-menus/) menu.

Comment: I had tried that. It sets it to Notepad++ Document, but for current default it lists XML Editor, which apparently is part of IE (?). Anyway, perhaps relevant is, in the traditional "open with" menu, N++ isn't listed alongside others, you have to browse manually.

Comment: I added a reference to the open with menu.

Comment: That isn't specifically the problem - it wasn't listed there before either, but it worked. Anyway, seeing as how it worked before, and it certainly should now, I don't think additional tools is needed for this, though that might be useful for other occasions.

Comment: At least for me the Default Programs / Set Associations works ok, it doesn't touch the file type description but immediately changes the default open behaviour to open in whatever is selected. @Pawnguy7: So when you select N++ in the dialog opened by Change program... button and hit ok, the Current default is still "XML Editor" in the file associations list?

Comment: Ah. It seems I was mistaken, sort of. I guess, by default, something is selected in the default program listings, and after selecting N++ via browse, they are still selected. Anyway, if I make it have nothing selected, then browse for N++, the button to apply it is grayed out. Note that N++ is not in the traditional programs directory. I think I had this issue before, but setting the associations from N++ itself fixed it, then, but unsetting/resetting them doesn't seem to have fixed it right now.